# TYPO3 Extbase: Domain model property with value NULL is not converted to zero when updating record in controller action

Tags: mysql, typo3, extbase, typo3-11.x

I'm stuck with the following problem:

> #1470230767 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Exception\SqlErrorException
>
> **Column 'linked_module' cannot be null**

I've got a domain model with this property:

```
/**
 * @var Module|null
 */
protected ?Module $linkedModule = null;
```

Module is just another domain model and this value is not mandatory. The database definition looks like this:

```
linked_module   int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
```

and last but not least the relevant TCA:

```
config => [
    'autoSizeMax' => 1,
    'default' => 0,
    'eval' => 'int',
    'foreign_table' => 'tx_psbriskassessment_domain_model_module',
    'items' => [
        ['---', 0],
    ],
    'maxitems' => 1,
    'minitems' => 0,
    'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
    'size' => 1,
    'type' => 'select',
]
```

In an action of my controller I want to reset the value of this property:

```
$module->setLinkedModule(null);
$this->moduleRepository->update($module);
```

This raises the exception (see beginning of this post).
I'm using **TYPO3 v11.5.4** and assumed that the DataMapper would convert NULL to 0 because of the eval=int. But that does not happen.

I dived into the core and reached the function persistObject() in `EXT:extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php` (line 295). If I read the code correctly, a NULL-value is always passed as NULL to the database - no conversion possible at this point.

I'm sure, I'm just missing a simple point. Disabling strict mode on the database server is no option for me. There has to be a clean solution.

Comment: "There has to be a clean solution"? And you want TYPO3/extbase to automatically convert given values? Maybe even in `strict_types` mode of PHP? Is that clean? IMO, the clean way would be to either allow writing the given value `null` in the database - or tell extbase what to do with values not allowed in your database definition. A simple way would be a more appropriate setter.

Comment: @JulianHofmann: You are right, I use strict mode in php. Writing NULL into the database would be a good solution. I tried it, but failed. Even with `'default' => null` and `'eval' => "null"`  in TCA, TYPO3 doesn't seem to allow it for a select field with a foreign_table:
SQL error: 'Incorrect integer value

Comment: There's no problem the other way round. When there's a 0 in the database, the DataMapper converts it to NULL when instantiating the object.

@JulianHofmann: It's a good question, if this is "clean". But that's the way TYPO3 handles domain objects (regarding automatic conversion of values when interacting with the database) and I want to keep close to conventions. I can't imagine that I'm addressing a rare use case here.

Comment: A 0 in a relation is not converted but *resolved* to null, because there's (normally) no object/record with UID=0 ;)  (Just tested this with a record having UID=0)

Comment: Hm... Interesting. Adding a new object with `null` is working. Updating does throw this error. You can solve it by not setting `null` but a new (empty) Module-object: $module->setLinkedModule(new Module());

Comment: I tested your idea. Unfortunately the empty module is added to the database as new record.

Comment: You're right :-( Ehm, do we have a convention to *not* use nullable columns?

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was sure, there has been a documentation about default database field definitions, but I was wrong. Maybe this assumption has been created by my early usages of the extension_builder-extension.

Conclusion: There's no reason to make this field not nullable!
I tried it again and it works. Simple enough. Backend and frontend behave like expected now. No idea, why there has been an error message on my first try. Perhaps some caching issues. Thank you very much for being persistent on this point.

Comment: Thank you for letting me dive deeper into this issue. Sometimes I have struggled with this, too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is different from 0. The relation could be to a record with UID 0 (which is unusual but not forbidden or prevented by design).

So, automatic conversion of a not-set relation (`$linkedModule = null`) to an integer 0 would falsify the information.

The simplest and cleanest way should be to define the database matching your model: without default value 0, but instead nullable.

```
linked_module   int(11) unsigned,
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with date fields (datetime objects) I was able to solve this with the setter in the model.

```
public function setLinkedModule ($linkedModule): void
{
    if(is_null($linkedModule)) {
        $this->linkedModule= 0;
    } else {
        $this->linkedModule= $linkedModule;
    }
}
```